# SQL statements to replace specific cell data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update data in a specific cell.  I have googled and I know I need to use UPDATE, but all of the examples I am seeing show how to change data in batches not for a single cell and I really don't want to mess this up.

So here is an example of my Answer table;

```
ID | Answer | User | Location 
1  | ans 1  | Usr1 | Loc 1
2  | ans 2  | Usr2 | Loc 2
3  | ans 3  | Usr3 | Loc 3
4  | ans 4  | Usr4 | Loc 4
```

So if I wanted to change the user from Usr3 to Usr2 in record 3, how would I write that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update answer set user = 'Usr2' where id = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

This article called "[SQL Update Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php)" should teach you what you need to know about updating specific tuples using SQL statements.

Essentially the statement goes like this:

```
  UPDATE table 
  SET  columnName1 = ?,
       columnName2 = ?',
  WHERE paramterToSearchForTuple = ?''
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!